# Losing data between xibs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to pass to another xib some data of NSMutableArray. I created a NSObject class called Gallery. Im loading it on both of views.

Im loading a XML that fills the NSMutableArray. Then, when i enter the first view, it fills the NSMutableArray perfectly, and gives me the content of it on a NSLog:

```
ProductPhotoGallery *telaGaleria = [[ProductPhotoGallery alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductPhotoGallery" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    Gallery *minhaGaleria = [[Gallery alloc] init];
    telaGaleria.galeria = minhaGaleria;
    telaGaleria.galeria.galeriaFotos =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    TBXMLElement * nodeFotos = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"fotos" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

    TBXMLElement * nodeFoto = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"foto" parentElement:nodeFotos];

    while (nodeFoto) {

        NSString * urlFoto = [TBXML textForElement:nodeFoto];   
        [telaGaleria.galeria.galeriaFotos addObject:urlFoto];
        NSLog(@"%@", urlFoto);
        nodeFoto = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"foto" searchFromElement:nodeFoto
                        ];
    }

    [telaGaleria release];

    NSLog(@"Array da Galeria %@", telaGaleria.galeria.galeriaFotos);
```

Giving me that correctly, i load the other view:

```
-(IBAction) vaiGaleria{

    ProductPhotoGallery *telaDaGaleria = [[ProductPhotoGallery alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductPhotoGallery" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    // Puxando a view

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:telaDaGaleria animated:YES];

    [telaDaGaleria release];


}
```

So, when the another view comes, i set to show the array on a log:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.galeria.galeriaFotos =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"ARRAY GALERIA DENTRO VIEW %@", self.galeria.galeriaFotos);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And it gives me null value. So, what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first line in `viewDidLoad` which releases your previously allocated array and allocates a new one.